# Google Apps Script to automatically open copied document after creating it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We are using sheets for our mom & pop store as our invoice.  However, my mother-in-law keeps saving over our invoice and we're always having to go back and delete the filled in sections.  She cannot seem to remember the steps of making a copy and then opening that.  I am using a script (button) to create a copy of the original and it is renamed as the customer name & date into a specific folder.  However, once we do that, we still have to navigate to the folder and open the new document.  Is there there a way to do this after I click the button on our original document to open of the copy that was made?  Here is the script that I am using.

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet()
{ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('Carolina Fireworks Order Form!C8');
  sheet.setNamedRange('TestRange', range);
  var TestRange = sheet.getRangeByName('Carolina Fireworks Order Form!C8').getValues();
  Logger.log(TestRange); 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1UdK90fEs3gkP4KZuUbmZbvvyVAW5ZMGw"); 
  let name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C8').getValue();
  const ds = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MM.dd.yy");
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy('TestRange', destFolder).setName(`${name}.${ds}`); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy('TestRange', destFolder).setName(`${name}.${ds}`);
```

#### To:

```
const file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy('TestRange', destFolder).setName(`${name}.${ds}`);
var js = `<script>window.open('${file.getUrl()}');google.script.host.close();</script>`;
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.');
```

- In this script, the URL is opened using Javascript on the dialog.
- This is from [this post](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/02/20/open-site-with-new-window-using-google-apps-script/)

#### Note:

- From [MetaMan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629210/google-apps-script-to-automatically-open-copied-document-after-creating-it#comment119538508_67629278)

  > If you want this to work you will have to disable popup blocking

#### References:

- [showModalDialog(userInterface, title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)
- [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: If you want this to work you will have to disable popup blocking

Comment: @MetaMan Thank you for your comment. I think that the information will be useful for OP and other users.

Comment: @tanaike Actually, I just noticed that it isn't opening the newly created one.  It is opening the original and not the copy that was made.

Comment: @Jab Burgess Thank you for replying. Your are correct! I forgot it. I apologize for this. Now, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In that case, in order to use the copied file, please use `file.getUrl()` instead of `sheet.getUrl()`. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: You are a godsend!  That did it!  I believe I accepted by hitting the green check mark.

Comment: @Jab Burgess Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Jab Burgess Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?